# Any reason my question has so little views?

Tags: discussion

My question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/438666/active-directory-integration-not-working-properly-with-winbind-and-samba) hasn't gotten that much attention.  Is there a way I can write it to invite more answers or comments?  Most, if not all, of the information I provide is necessary to have an understanding of the situation.

Comment: Note to future attention to this question, I was just looking for feedback on my style of question asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is barely a day old. Patience is a virtue, grasshopper.

Comment: *le sigh*  You're right.  It's just that this issue has been going on for a while and I had posted about it before.  I'll just cross my legs and sit quietly.

Comment: I gave you my best guess at an answer (UID overlaps are bad, mmkay?) :)

Comment: If you posted it before: is this one a duplicate of an older one?

Comment: Neither.  The specifics of the question changed.  Thus I deleted the previous and reposted with the new information.

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the FAQ? It contains information that would be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  voretaq7 provided a relevant answer already.

Comment: Just because one answer is relevant doesn't mean the other isn't.